# PHP Laravel Passing Model as function parameter

Tags: php, laravel

I need to pass a model to a function, but seem that my solution is not correct because i receive below error from PHPStorm

*expects parameter of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model, string given.*

this an extract of my code:

```
 /** Return the model structure
  *
  * @param \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model $model
  * @param array $fillData
  * @return object
  */
public static function fillBasicModelData(Model $model, $fillData){
 ...code...
}
```

And below is how I call the function:

```
$result = self::fillBasicModelData(Filter::class, $emptyFilter);
```

Obviously Filter is an Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model

so my question is how can I pass a model to a function without this warning?

thank you

Comment: you should pass a class object, not the class name.

Comment: Thank you, this can be a good solution or there is a better way?

            $model = new Filter; 
            $result = self::fillBasicModelData($model, $emptyFilter);

Comment: try $result = self::fillBasicModelData((new Filter()), $emptyFilter);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Obviously Filter is an Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model

No it isn't. You are passing it with `Filter::class`. This is the class of the model, not an instance. Basically it translates to the string `'\NameSpace\SomeThing\Filter'`

Because you are passing the class, and not a model instance, you need it instantiate the model.

```php
public static function fillBasicModelData($model_class, $fillData){
 $model = new $model_class($fillData);
 // ...code...
}
```

Comment: thank you, how can I pass the model instead the class?  I also try to pass the model with
self::fillBasicModelData(Filter, $emptyFilter); but seem not work :(

Comment: You need to instantiate the model yourself. `$filter = new Filter(); self::fillBasicModelData($filter, $emptyFilter);`